# Unix grep all that doesn't follow decimal pattern of size

Tags: unix, grep, decimal

So I have a list of values

```
123.45
7739.6
7398
777777.0
1.2333333
3.3.3
Shdkv
.0
0.
.
```

And I would like to grep the lines that doesn't fit (example) nullable decimal[6,2]

Which would be

```
777777.0
1.2333333
3.3.3
Shdkv
.
```

I can select each criteria individually (such as length more than or doesn't contain letters) but I can't do them all properly. Additionally, a decimal point by itself ,".", should not be considered a number

I didn't know you can specify the length for before and after the decimal point so I tried to used sed select the before and after the decimal point and check them separately

```
sed -e  's/^[^\.]*\.//'| grep -E -v "^-? ?[0-9]{0,$dec_length}
sed -e 's/\.//'| grep -E -v "^-? ?[0-9]{0,$int_length}
```

however it doesn't work for cases that doesn't have a decimal point

I also tried to use awk instead, by recommendation of my friend, but i ran to similar problem.

Currently, thanks to tripleeee's suggestion, I am here

```
sed -e 's/\+//' -e 's/\-//'|  grep -E -v '^-?[0-9]{0,$int_length}(\.?[0-9]{0,dec_length}?)$'
```

Comment: The close reason here is slightly misleading. There are not really multiple questions here. We used to have a "too broad" reason which included "lacks effort or demonstration of any research" but the correct close reason now would really be "needs details or clarity". Anyway, please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask;](/help/how-to-ask) perhaps you can still edit this into a form which is acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Probably try a regex tutorial before asking for trivial regular expressions.

```
grep -E '^-?[1-9]{0,6}(\.[0-9]{0,2}?)$'
```

This requires a number before the point. Leave out the `-?` to only allow non-negative floats. Search for existing questions if this is not precisely what you need (your requirements are unclear with regard to some corner cases, like is `.` a valid float?)

Comment: I did tried something like this but it would allow for values such as 1.000 which should not be

Comment: Your question would be much better if you showed what you have tried and explained which parts you think are hard.

Comment: Hi so I just tried using
grep -E -v '^-?[1-9]{0,6}(\.[0-9]{0,2}?)$' but it doesn't work for .1234 I will try to clearify the initial question

Comment: Probably search before asking. There are many, many, many questions about how to write a regex for a floating-point number with various constraints around the corner cases.